# Check variable text inside a textarea

Tags: jquery

I've a textarea in a page config.php where I can save a text with some placeholder replaced by PHP before load in another page send.php:

My placeholder are something like: {name}, {surname}, {others}, {sometext},...

Example page `config.php`

```
<textarea>Dear {name}, this is the list of your products: {others}</textarea>
```

Then, when I load send.php:

```
<?php

$info_user = get_info_user($id);

$text = load_text_from_page_config();

$replacements = array(
                '({name})' => $info_user['name'], //John
                '({surname})' => $info_user['surname'] //Smith
            );
            $text = preg_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ), $text);

echo '<textarea>' . $text . '</textarea>';
```

So in this my example I get:

```
<textarea>Dear John, this is the list of your products: {others}</textarea>
```

I want, when I click a submit button, to check if there are some placeholder still in my text area. (In my case `{others}` is not present). In this case I want to show an alert in JavaScript/jQuery:

```
alert("There are still placeholder in your text. Retry again");
```

My final question is: how to find a text, with jQuery, delimited by { and } but where I don't know exact text inside it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit-button").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var text = $("textarea").val();

    if ( //here the check ) {

    return false;   

    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a regular expression to find any values which are wrapped in `{}`:

```js
$('textarea').each(function() {
  var hasTags = /\{.*\}/gi.test($(this).text());
  console.log(hasTags);
});
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Lorem ipsum {dolor} sit amet consectetur adipiscing {elit}</textarea>
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</textarea>
```

Note that this is a greedy match, so if there is a `{` followed by a `}` at any point in the textarea it will pass that test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex as follows

```
const regex = /\{.*?\}/gm;
let matches;
if((matches = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
 //do whatever you want
}
```